# Dynamically resize the menu in CSS

Tags: css, menu, resize

I was just wondering how can I dynamically change size of my menu at the top("Linear Algebra","Discrete Maths") whenever a user changes the size of the browser's window? I've tried changing the width to percentage, but it did not work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "home.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "#"> Discrete Maths </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                </ul><!-- end of the inner ul-->
            </li><!-- end of the main li-->
        </ul><!-- end of the main ul-->

        <ul>
            <li><a href = "#"> Linear Algebra </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                </ul><!-- end of the inner ul-->
            </li><!-- end of the main li-->
        </ul><!-- end of the main ul-->

        <ul>
            <li><a href = "#"> Calculators </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link item</a></li>
                </ul><!-- end of the inner ul-->
            </li><!-- end of the main li-->
        </ul><!-- end of the main ul-->

        <ul>
            <li><a href = "#" id = "search"> Search </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">
                            <input type = "text" id = "text"></input>
                            <input type = "button" value = "szukaj"></input>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li><!-- end of the main li-->
        </ul><!-- end of the main ul-->
    </div><!-- end of the menu-->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css

```
body {
    background-color: #562500;
    background: url('image_for_website.jpg') repeat;
}
#menu {    
    width: 70%;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
            box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 2px #1F0000;
       -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 2px #1F0000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 2px #1F0000;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#menu li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}
#menu ul li a {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 234px;
    display: block;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    height: 39px;
}
#menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 40px;
    top: 39px;
}
#menu ul li: hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    background: rgba(51,23,0,1.0);
}
#menu ul li: hover ul li {
    border: 1px inset black;
    margin: 0px -1px;
}
#menu ul li: hover ul li a: hover {
    background: rgba(64,21,0,0.5);
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fTe8V/

Comment: What seems to be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use use jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    // You could do some checks here to see what size the window is
    var height = $(this).height();
    $(menu).css('height','20px'); // Set the height of the menu
});
```

Comment: It's not what I wanted.You see,when I'm resizing the window to like very small size in width, my menu items go wherever they want and stick one under the other so they are no longer in my menu bar,but somewhere else

Comment: I see what you're saying... set a min-width to your menu. #menu {min-width: 600px}, this way it doesn't effect the menu when you resize. Right now though, 600px isn't wide enough. You should shrink your menu size. Instead of using 70% width, you could use margins to push it off the edges.

Comment: Great,thanx.It helped me to do what I wanted.